# Parse score reports and extract point sums and averages

Tags: linux, bash

i want to calculate:

- the total points (sum)
- the today points (sum)
- the total points (average)
- the today points (average)

i have no idea with bash scripting other than i need to start with: #!/bin/bash

here's a sample of my file

```
#file 14516 - 2011-01-26 19:01:00 EDT#
user: xxxxxxxx@email.com / id(11451611)
lastlogin: 1295896515
total_points: 11.76 / today: 5.21
gameid: 51

user: xxxxxxxx@email.com / id(11837327)
lastlogin: 1293893041
total_points: 416.1 / today: 98.1
gameid: 49

user: xxxxxxxx@email.com / id(11451611)
lastlogin: 1294917135
total_points: 1.76 / today: 0.21
gameid: 51
```

Comment: For people to help you - you need to make an effort yourself

Comment: You want this done in Bash scripting?

Comment: So why don't you read a bash programming guide first, then ask questions that are not answered in the guide already? Why wasting people's time? If you want someone else to do it for you - hire a programmer to do it.

Comment: "other than i need to start with: `#!/bin/bash`" - and you don't even have _that_ right. You should be using `/usr/bin/env bash` :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -f $1 ]; then
  echo "File $1 not found"
  exit 1
fi

number=$(grep total_points $1 | wc -l )
sumTotal=$(grep total_points $1 | awk '{sum+=$2} END { print sum }')
sumToday=$(grep total_points $1 | awk '{sum+=$5} END { print sum }')

echo "Total SUM: $sumTotal"
echo -n "Total AVG: "
echo "scale=5;$sumTotal/$number" | bc

echo "Today SUM: $sumToday"
echo -n "Today AVG: "
echo "scale=5;$sumToday/$number" | bc
```

Then save to a file like: `script.sh`

Change the permission to executable: `chmod +x script.sh`

Then run it: `./script.sh sample.txt`

This will output:

```
Total Record: 3
Total SUM: 429.62
Total AVG: 143.20666
Today SUM: 103.52
Today AVG: 34.50666
```

Note:
`$1` will the the input file.

Here's more help about the [bc command](http://www.basicallytech.com/blog/index.php?/archives/23-command-line-calculations-using-bc.html), [grep](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ugrep.htm), [awk](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)